# Is it possible to allow cross-domain requests through the use of CNAME records?

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, cname

I know there are very many cross-domain questions but I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for.

I'd like to make an client AJAX request from a.com to b.com, which obviously isn't allowed. I thought that if I created a b.a.com -> b.com CNAME record then the browser would allow this request, since it means whoever owns the a.com domain wants to explicitly allow requests to b.com, but I still get a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error that doesn't allow the request. Is it not possible to make this request happen with CNAMEs?

Note: I have no control over b.com, so I can't set headers there.

Answer (score 14):

No. (But I have a real explaination)

The "rules of the road" for "cross-domain requests" are generally governed by the "Same Origin Policy" (see: [The W3C Commentary](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), [Google Browser Security Handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript))

The W3C specifically states that:

> An origin is defined by the scheme, host, and port of a URL.

According to this definition, even requests from `foo.com` to `bar.foo.com` would be blocked.

In your example, you suggest that creating a `CNAME` for `bar.foo.com` which points at `bar.com` (I'm assuming you had a typo) should allow requests to `bar.com` via `bar.foo.com`. But, as I stated above, even requests originating from `foo.com` would be blocked on the client side from making HTTP requests to `bar.foo.com`.

Mozilla's page even has this specific example:

> Mozilla considers two pages to have the same origin if the protocol,
>   port (if one is specified), and host are the same for both pages. The
>   following table gives examples of origin comparisons to the URL
>   http://store.company.com/dir/page.html:
>
> URL | Outcome | Reason
>
> http://store.company.com/dir2/other.html | Success
>   http://store.company.com/dir/inner/another.html | Success
>   https://store.company.com/secure.html | Failure | Different protocol
>   http://store.company.com:81/dir/etc.html | Failure | Different port
>   **http://news.company.com/dir/other.html | Failure | Different host**

Answer (score 2):

No.

I have never heard of CNAME as a way of getting around this problem, so I think it is safe to assume it is not a solution to your problem.